# Change how answers are sorted in the Stack Exchange app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, mobile-app

On the web you can choose how answers are sorted.

You can choose by:

- Active
- Oldest
- Votes

How are answers sorted in the app? Can an option be added to choose how they are sorted?

EDIT:

If answers are sorted by votes surely accepted answers should be at the top.

Why is this happening:

[image]

Comment: I thought app development was officially dead. Supposed to visit the site on a mobile browser now.

Comment: What question has the accepted answer below other answers? I can't repro that

Comment: @astonearachnid if it's a self-accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers on the iOS app are sorted the same way as the votes tab on the full site. This means:

- Answers with higher scores are shown higher. Answers that are tied are shown in a random order
- The accepted answer is shown above all answers **unless it’s a self answer**. Self answers are sorted normally, so they have to outscore the other answers to be shown first

If you need answers to be sorted a different way, you can use the `Inquestion:###` search operator, where the numbers are the ID of the question:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. The mobile app is not being developed, but you can change the sort when using the web version from a mobile device.
2. In your [example question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90248/macbook-pro-only-charging-when-turned-off), the answer is self-accepted. On the web site, it also appears below the top. This seems to be intended behavior:
   [image]

Comment: Because they have the same score, they appear in either order. But we don't pin accepted answers that were written by the asker. They need to actually outscore the others to appear at the top.